# install -D /dev/null path_file functionality in Python

Tags: python, bash, touch, mkdir

In BASH, to create a file and the parent directories it may have, it can be done `install -D /dev/null file_name`.

For example:

```
install -D /dev/null /var/tmp/an-example/example_file.txt
```

would create the full directory structure, **/var/tmp/an-example/**, and the empty file, **example_file.txt**.

I wonder if in Python there's an easy pythonic way to do the same, apart from using subprocess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was checking, and I found myself an easy way just after posting...

**Valid for Python >= 3.5**

```
from pathlib import Path
# ...

# creates directories structure, like mkdir -p <directories> would do
Path(file_with_path[:file_with_path.rfind("/")]).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

# creates the empty file, as touch <filename> would do:
Path(file_with_path).touch()
```